# Permission denied when I run git add

Tags: git, permissions, permission-denied

When I run the code:

git add .

I got this:

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Low/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temp/RarSFX0/packages/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Music/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Videos/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
error: open(".gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/samples/plugins/multiproject/maven-repo/org/gradle/sample/goodbye/org.gradle.sample.goodbye.gradle.plugin/1.0.0/org.gradle.sample.goodbye.gradle.plugin-1.0.0.pom.md5"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file '.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/samples/plugins/multiproject/maven-repo/org/gradle/sample/goodbye/org.gradle.sample.goodbye.gradle.plugin/1.0.0/org.gradle.sample.goodbye.gradle.plugin-1.0.0.pom.md5'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Can someone please advice me on how I can fix it?

Comment: where are you running this command. I am sure you are not pointed correct folder to run git add command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning+could+not+open+directory+Permission+denied

Answer (score 1):

It could be two things that I can thinks right now:

1. The first one is that you are runnning the git add command outside of an initialized git folder. did you run git init?
2. Could be that probably you need to close the project you are working on and then try to add, because sometimes, ides, editor or wherever your work on, can block the files, so git cannot access those files.

Comment: I changed the directory then it worked correctly